# Redirect to https:// and remove www. in htaccess on WordPress site

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to redirect to `https://` on my website and remove any `www.` subdomain in the url using htaccess on my WordPress site, because my security certificate doesn't cover the `www` subdomain. This is almost working:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.
RewriteCond http%1://%{HTTP_HOST} ^(https?://)(www\.)?(.+)$
RewriteRule ^ https://%3%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>   

# END WordPress
```

This redirects to `https://` and removes `www.` from `http://` urls. However, it doesn't remove the subdomain if the `https://` is already there, so e.g. `http://www.example.com` is changed to `https://example.com`, but `https://www.example.com` remains unchanged.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does your website use multiple dns names or `(www.)example.com` is the only two?

Comment: `RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|off` - what’s that supposed to achieve? If you don’t care whether the it is on or off, then why this check in the first place? And why `on(s)`?

Comment: @dusan There are a few sub domains that are served from a different dns.

Comment: I think @Dusan’s question rather meant whether the `example.com` part is always the same ... in that case you could hard-code it, and also specifically check for whether the requested host name was `www.example.com` - keeping this static is usually easier, than operating with %{HTTP_HOST} and trying to get the partial hostname to redirect to dynamically from there.

Comment: @CBroe Good point, removed, still having the same problem.

Comment: @CBroe, ah, okay, yes it is. What would that look like in full?

Comment: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$` - only for this specific host name, all other subdomains or `example.com` aren’t relevant. `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on` - only if HTTPS is not already used. `RewriteRule . https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]` - something like that. RewriteConds are combined with an implicit logical AND, but since you want to redirect when either one of those is not met, put `[OR]` behind the first condition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be as simple as this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example.com
RewriteRule ^ https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,QSA]
```

Comment: This still works as above on internet explorer, it won't remove the www if https is already there. Works in Chrome, but I assume this is as Chrome removes the www by default.

Comment: Make sure you test from clean browser.

Comment: I think the issue is that the security certificate on the site is not accommodating for www., and IE is freaking out and blocking the site before it has a change to rewrite it; when I follow the link through from the warning page, it redirects as expected. Does that sound right? If so, I'm not going to be able to fix this with code, I'm going to have to get a new certificate.

Comment: Exactly, you need the proper cert even if you only want to do the redirect. But they are cheap or even free these days.

Comment: Accepted, as even though my problem turned out to be something else, this was the correct answer to question asked. People finding this from Google, see my comment above re certificates.

Answer (score 0):

You could exclude main domain to match all sub domain + remove wwww + force https :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?maindomain\.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off  [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(.+)$
RewriteRule ^  https://%2%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Then , If you want to force maindomain only use this :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?maindomain\.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off  
RewriteRule ^  https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

But maindomain will be forced into https as it is , if you want to remove or add www let me know

**NOTE:** Clear browser cache then test